# Do we have SQL Server like User Defined Functions in Google Big Query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have been using Big query extensively for sometime in our company. We had been writing some reusable utility logic(say computing distance in miles between two geo-coordinates) in our Queries.
Found 'User Defined Function(UDF)' in Big Query that is something near my requirement but the problem with UDFs is that they are not reusable and TEMPORARY in nature as they cannot be persisted at one place, and referred across the queries. UDFs need to be duplicated per query to be referred or they are only locally referable to a query.

I am looking for something very similar to SQL Server/Oracle User Defined Functions that can be created, managed and referred.

Do we have some graceful solution for this, in Big Query as of today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery supports persistent user-defined functions. To get started, see [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_function_statement).

For example, here's a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement that creates a function to compute the median of an array:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dataset.median(arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  (
    SELECT
      IF(
        MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 0,
        (arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] + arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]) / 2,
        arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]
      )
    FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x) AS arr FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x)
  )
);
```

After executing this statement, you can reference it in a follow-up query:

```sql
SELECT dataset.median([7, 1, 2, 10]) AS median;
```

Comment: I would rather added this as a comment or update to existing answer :o) in any case - great job BigQuery Team! thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks Elliott, for adding this answer. Though, this is in beta release but nevertheless, it paves the way for Persistent functions in BIG QUERY, a long overdue FR :)